# Spark structured streaming does not restart from previous offset

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a streaming spark application which reads messages from kafka stream as below;

```
    m_kafkaEvents = m_sparkSession.readStream().format("kafka")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", strKafkaAddress)
        .option("subscribe", InsightConstants.IP_INSIGHT_EVENT_TOPIC)
        .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", "100000")
        .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
        .option("failOnDataLoss", false)
        .load()
        .select(
            functions.col("key").cast("string").as(InsightConstants.IP_SYS_INSTANCE_ID), 
            functions.col("value").cast("string").as("event"),
            functions.col("partition"),
            functions.col("offset"))
        .as(ExpressionEncoder.javaBean(InputEvent.class));
```

Then I process the message and write into the Kakfa output sink as below;

```
 DataStreamWriter<SessionUpdate> eventsStream = sessionUpdates
        .writeStream()
        .queryName(strQueryName)
        .outputMode("append")        .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(m_insightDeployment.getIdentifierProcessor().getTriggerInterval()))
        .option("checkpointLocation", strCheckpointLocation)
        .foreach(foreachWriter);
```

In ForeachWriter,

I push the message into the kafka topic as below;

```
    try
    {
      String strKafkaAddress = m_strKafkaHost + ":" + m_iKafkaPort.toString();
      Properties oProperties = new Properties();
      oProperties.put("bootstrap.servers", strKafkaAddress);
      oProperties.put("acks",              "all");
      oProperties.put("retries",           3);
      oProperties.put("batch.size",        16384);
      oProperties.put("linger.ms",         1);
      oProperties.put("buffer.memory",     33554432);
      oProperties.put("key.serializer",    "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
      oProperties.put("value.serializer",  "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

      m_oProducer = new org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer<String, String>(oProperties);
    }
    catch (Throwable oThrowable)
    {
      oThrowable.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

    ProducerRecord<String, String> oMessage =
        new ProducerRecord<String, String>(in_strTopic, in_strKey, in_strPayload);

      m_oProducer.send(oMessage);
```

With this code when the spark app restarts(*I kill it manually via console and after some time spark app restarts on it own by driver*), it will again read the message from start instead of previous offset based on the checkpoint.
I see checkpoint location is created and it looks like spark app does not read from that checkpoint location. Hence I see duplicate messages.

It looks like am missing something here. Can someone please recommend what is the missing part here?

Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Do you see `offsets` under checkpoint location? What is the values there?

Comment: Yes. I can something like   -rw-r--r-- insight supergroup 230 B 8/22/2018, 9:54:26 PM 1 128 MB 0
-rw-r--r-- insight supergroup 257 B 8/22/2018, 9:57:03 PM 1 128 MB 1
-rw-r--r-- insight supergroup 260 B 8/22/2018, 10:03:30 PM 1 128 MB 2